# How to parse ksoap array response Webservice soap in android

Tags: android

I have a webservice that throwing a array set of data. I'm using Ksoap to get the response from my webservice:

anyType{Nombre=Hector; ApellidoPat=Guzman; ApellidoMat=Henriquez; Rut=16112663; Id=8; Estadistica=anyType{TotalHoras=530:49:40; TotalHorasExtra=0:00:00; Licencias=0:00:00; TotalAtrasos=15:55:01; }; MarcaHoy=anyType{MarcasHoyData=anyType{Fecha=30-04-2014; Hora=30-04-2014 9:52:36; Tipo=0; Serie=0000000000000355847050419881; }; MarcasHoyData=anyType{Fecha=30-04-2014; Hora=30-04-2014 9:52:38; Tipo=1; Serie=0000000000000355847050419881; }; MarcasHoyData=anyType{Fecha=30-04-2014; Hora=30-04-2014 9:52:40; Tipo=0; Serie=0000000000000355847050419881; }; MarcasHoyData=anyType{Fecha=30-04-2014; Hora=30-04-2014 9:52:42; Tipo=1; Serie=0000000000000355847050419881; }; MarcasHoyData=anyType{}; }; }

Can anyone give a tutorial or suggestion how to parse this response?

Answer (score 0):

Please, first try looking for on internet. Read KSoap response is an old theme. Look this http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=2594 (Spanish)
http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/15/introduction-to-working-with-ksoap2-in-android/ (English)